# How do 2 SMTP servers authentificate to each other?

Tags: email, smtp

When a SMTP relay A forwards a message, it looks up the MX record of the target address, then forwards the email to the SMTP server B that this record points to.
But how does A prove its identity to B?

(I would like to send emails from my domain name)

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentication for general SMTP server to SMTP server communication.
SMTP was designed long time ago in "small & friendly internet" era.

There are later added "tricks" to reject spam anyway e.g.

- rejecting "bad" IP addresses based on locally selected set of [DNSBLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL), some DNSBLs list [DUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic/Dialup_Users_Lis) ranges
- rejecting based on locally gathered non published reputation (especially by big mail services)
- …